# Minimizing a floor expression

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Consider the expression

$$ax - b\left\lfloor\frac{cx}{m}\right\rfloor$$

Variables $a, b, c, m$ are positive integers (all of which are known), and $x$ is an unknown integer.

The bounds on $x$ are $1 \leq x \lt m$.

Is there an efficient way to find the minimal value of this expression instead of looping over all $1 \leq x \lt m$?